# asp:Label with nested control disappears on setting CssClass

Tags: asp.net

Is it improper to nest another control within asp:Label?

When I have another control (e.g., a button) inside my asp:Label, and I try to change CssClass on the label during an event handler, the entire label seems to disappear. I'll be grateful if someone can help me find what I might be doing wrong.

Bad1.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Bad1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Bad1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Badness?</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="check and uncheck me" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" /> 
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" > See me now? <asp:Button runat="server" /> </asp:Label>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Bad1.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Bad1 : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var lab = Page.FindControl("Label1") as Label;
        lab.CssClass = "foo";
    }
}
```

Symptom: Page displays correctly at first, and after first click on "check and uncheck me". But when I click on the checkbox a second time, the label ("See me now") disappears, never to come back. If I remove the button from within the label, there's no problem. So, is the nesting what's incorrect?

Comment: Just curious..why would you want to put a button inside a label?

Comment: Erroneous distillation of my problem code on my part. I'd had label-in-label, but am no longer a label abuser in that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into using a Panel instead of a Label.

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="someStyle">
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Hi"></asp:Button>
</asp:Panel>
```

If you're looking to style the button, then you should apply your CssClass to the button directly. Use a Panel if you're trying to apply a style to that region/block.

Comment: Thank you, James. Your comment led me to investigate Panels and onward to PlaceHolder which seems to be what I'd really needed. I'd distilled things down too far, it seems, in posting my question (button inside label was not my goal, only seemed to manifest the behavior I was asking about). My original question, still unanswered, is now purely academic. Thanks much for your helpful response!